# In VueJS, how do I use load in a view based on what is populated in my JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.JS and require a little help as I am stuck with some logic.
I have been given a project to building and as I am under NDA I can only show comparative code examples.

In one View (Bars), which is brought into the viewport of the application using the router, I have a simple for loop.

```
<ul class="bar-listings">
  <li v-for="bar in bars">
      <router-link to="{bar.barPage}">
          <div class="item">
             <div class="item-bd">
                 <h2>{{ bar.barName }}</h2>
             </div>
          </div>
      </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in my JS file conatining all my data, I have this (Only one object for now)

```
export default [
  {
    barName: "The Tropicana Bar",
    barPage: "views/bars/Tropicana",
  }
];
```

The title displays correctly on Bars so the loop is pulling the data correctly.

However, I will have a .vue file for each bar, which also uses the data from my JS file. See below:

```
<template>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h1>{{ getBarByIndex({ bars, index }).barName }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import bars from "./../../data/bars";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bars: bars
    };
  },
  methods: {
  getBarByIndex({ bars = [], index = 0 }) {
    return bars[index] || {}
  }
}
};
</script>
```

So what I need to solve is how do I make the `<a v-bind:href="">` load the view for this bar?

Comment: Yes, I am using vue router to load Home | Bars | Contact Therefore, I have set up these routes on my router.js. Navigate to /bars and it pulls in the bars view with the loop for a list of bars. But now I want to select a bar from the list and that would change the view to see the Bar Details page. :)

Comment: i guess what you need lies here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

Comment: I can see the logic of using the router, so have updated my code above. However, it still doesnt contain anything that will change the view (Just the string {bar.barPage})

Comment: It should be :to="..." else its interpreted as string

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do, is to have a child component inside your component, you can leverage this by using nested routes in your router-view, additionally, you can pass props as an object to your router components, parent or child, whatever you need.

Basically, you will have a main router view, but inside your component, you will have another router-view which renders child components.

[See: Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

[See: Passing Props to Route components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components)

Comment: Thanks will take a look. Its a bit like having a news app which has a news listings page, using a loop to print each iteration. Pulling the title and a synopsis from the databasee. Then you click on a news title to read the story, this changes the view to the news details (not navigating away to a static page and leaving the app)